# IE automation with c#, selenium and jquery - random from dynamic table

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium-webdriver, random, automation

I have a dynamic table - it mean that every time it could has different num of rows

I need to choose one row (never-mind which one [random]) and than continue to the next step

I really don't know how to start and would like have your help

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "table" in this context? A `<table>` element in a web page? A table in a database? If the latter, what database software (SQL Server etc) are you using? If you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question showing what you're trying to do, then it'll help us to understand your question better and increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I meant to a table element :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I created a NUnit test project and added the Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver NuGet packages. I added a file called page.html to the project, set its "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy always" and added the following markup - this is just so that I've got a page to work with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td>4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>6</td><td>6</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my test:

```
namespace StackOverflow68649351RandomRow
{
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            try
            {
                var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"file://{path}/page.html");

                // Get the table by ID - don't want to assume that it's the only table on the page
                var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myTable"));

                // Get all the rows in the table
                var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

                // pick a random row
                var random = new Random();
                var rowNumber = random.Next(rows.Count - 2) + 1; // use this line to exclude the header row
                // var rowNumber = random.Next(rows.Count - 1); // use this line to include the header row
                var row = rows[rowNumber];

                // Do something with the row
                Console.WriteLine(row.Text);
            }
            finally
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what's happening here?

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns the path to the project's output folder, which is where the compiler will have copied my page.html file to, so I can use this in the next line to build the file:// URL to the file and navigate to it. This is all part of the slightly contrived way of having a page to work with, and is only needed to make this particular example work.

Next, we find the table using its ID property. This gives us an `IWebElement` representing the table.

Because `IWebElement` has `FindElement`, `FindElements`, etc methods just as `IWebDriver` does, we can use the table's `FindElements` method to find all the table's child elements which are `tr` elements, i.e. all the rows in the table.

Then we get a random number to use as an index into the collection of rows. This number must have a maximum value of 1 less than the number of rows. If we want to allow the header row to be selected then the minimum value must be 0, otherwise it must be 1.

Finally, `rows[rowNumber]` is the row we've selected at random.

This example uses NUnit as the test runner and the ChromeDriver implementation of `IWebDriver`, but it should work the same way for any browser and test runner.

A note of caution - if your table contains another table, this method could pick a row either from the outer table or the inner table, although as the question doesn't mention tables within tables, I haven't catered for that possibility in the interests of simplicity.